# MySQL Update Linked Table If Master Table Has New Records

Tags: mysql

I need to compare two tables that are linked by Foreign Key and add records from the master table that are not already in the linked table with foreign key. What's the best way to go about doing this please?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on master table that will be triggered when there's a new insert to the master table.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER master_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON linked_table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   -- Insert record into linked_table
   INSERT INTO linked_table
   ( id,
     some_value,
     master_id)
   VALUES
   ( 1,
     'test value',
     NEW.id ); // <-- using NEW you can get newly inserted record

END; //
```

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to do the trick for me:

```
INSERT into table2 (foreignkey_id) 
SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foreignkey_id FROM table2)
```